# Change mtrs, feet conversion based on radio button in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

> Blockquote
>   i have select drop down option to convert the number to meter and fett,its working fine but i need same functionality as a radio button,
>   so instead of drop down i need two radio button,one for meter and one for feet,so how to change the code according to radio in angular

```js
$scope.change = function() {
  if ($scope.data.previousSel != $scope.data.selectedOption) {
    if ($scope.data.selectedOption.name == 'feet') {
      var feets = $scope.data.previousSel.id * $scope.data.selectedOption.id;
      angular.forEach($scope.choices, function(choice) {
        choice.l2 = feets * choice.l2;
        choice.b2 = feets * choice.b2;
        choice.d2 = feets * choice.d2;
      });
    }
    if ($scope.data.selectedOption.name == 'mtrs') {
      var mtrs = $scope.data.previousSel.id / $scope.data.selectedOption.id;
      angular.forEach($scope.choices, function(choice) {
        choice.l2 = choice.l2 / mtrs;
        choice.b2 = choice.b2 / mtrs;
        choice.d2 = choice.d2 / mtrs;
      });
    }

    $scope.data.previousSel = $scope.data.selectedOption;
  }
};
$scope.data = {
  availableOptions: [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'mtrs'
  }, {
    id: '3.28',
    name: 'feet'
  }],
  previousSel: {
    id: '1',
    name: 'mtrs'
  },
  selectedOption: {
    id: '1',
    name: 'mtrs'
  } //This sets the default value of the select in the ui

};
```

```html
<p>Select a unit:</p>
<select ng-change="change()" ng-model="data.selectedOption" ng-options="option.name for option in data.availableOptions track by option.id">
</select>
```